# How to remove element in list after replacing, in a loop for next largest in list

Tags: python

Write a function that replaces each integer with the next largest in the list.
Examples
replace_next_largest([5, 7, 3, 2, 8]) ➞ [7, 8, 5, 3, -1]
replace_next_largest([2, 3, 4, 5]) ➞ [3, 4, 5, -1]
replace_next_largest([1, 0, -1, 8, -72]) ➞ [8, 1, 0, -1, -1]

https://afteracademy.com/blog/find-the-next-greater-element-for-every-element-in-an-array

?? did not pop after replace next largest in list

```
def replaceNextLargest(numLst):

    result = []

    for i in range(len(numLst)):
        found = False
        for j in range(len(numLst)):
            if numLst[j] > numLst[i]:
                found = True
                result.append(numLst[j])
                break
        if found == False:
            result.append(-1)

    return result

print( replaceNextLargest( [5, 7, 3, 2, 8] ))
return [7, 8, 5, 5, -1]
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? the question that you ask has no relevance to the code you posted. and to remove the 2nd largest number, you could just sort the array in descending and remove the 2nd element...

Comment: the code did not remove the element after replacing. for example the iteration loop to replace next largest should be 57328--75328--78325--78523--78532--7853-1 so element 8 after replaced will be remove, which the code did not manage to encounter for.

Comment: are you trying to remove the largest number in the list?

Comment: yes, on every iteration after it has been replaced

Comment: Better remove the magic square part if it is not related to the question. Your code just iterate and append, without anything related to pop or remove, while the example in your comment seems to be doing swap. Try to add your expected result for clarification.

Comment: thanks. just edit the question. I tried to remove but it remove entirely from the list, even after being replaced. so I'm not sure where to insert result.remove(numLst[i]) ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this bro
just add a check if the element already exist or not i think it may works
if it fails at condition please comment

```
def replaceNextLargest(numLst):

    result = []

    for i in range(len(numLst)):
        found = False
        for j in range(len(numLst)):
            print(numLst[j], numLst[i])
            if numLst[j] > numLst[i] and numLst[j] not in result :
                found = True
                result.append(numLst[j])
                break
        if found == False:
            result.append(-1)

return result

print( replaceNextLargest( [5, 7, 3, 2, 8] ))
```

Comment: wow it works ! thanks Sarath ! beginner here. do you mind explain to me what does this mean please?  --> if numLst[j] > numLst[i] and numLst[j] not in result :

Comment: thank you please vote the answer bro if you don't mind

Comment: i just checked for the value if it currently exist in your result. if exist we don’t want to check the value

Comment: great. very helpful !